# How to align underlines in a cases environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, cases, alignment

Please consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
f(t)=\begin{cases}
    2t+1&\text{if \(0\leq t\leq2\)},\\
    \hrulefill&\text{if \(\_ <t<\_\)},
    \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

How can we align the last two `\_` to position them at the same height as `\hrulefill`? Something like:

[image: What I want]

Also we need to position the `<`, `>` and the last `t` with the above.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just work with phantoms in this case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
f(t)=\begin{cases}
    2t+1&\text{if \(0\leq t\leq2\)},\\
    \underline{\phantom{2t+1}}&\text{if \(\underline{\phantom{0}} <t<\underline{\phantom{2}}\)},
    \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and understandable solution!!

Answer (score 4):

The `\hrulefill` command expands to

```
\leavevmode \leaders \hrule \hfill \kern \z@`
```

So one way to do what you want is to use `\hrule`, or better `\rule`, instead of `\_`.  If you define

```
\newcommand\blank{\rule{2mm}{0.4pt}}
```

then you can use it to produce:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\blank{\rule{2mm}{0.4pt}}

\begin{document}
\[
f(t)=\begin{cases}
    2t+1&\text{if \(0\leq t\leq2\)},\\
    \hrulefill&\text{if \(\blank <t<\blank\)},
    \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Since you are already using [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) I'd also recommend using the `cases*` environment so that you can omit the `\text{...}` commands when using cases. Unfortunately, `\hrulefill` does not work inside a `cases*` environment, so here is a fancier version of the `\blank` command that takes an optional argument that sets the length of the blank to the length of the supplied content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\blank[1][$\_$]{\rule{\widthof{#1}}{0.4pt}}

\begin{document}
\[
f(t)=\begin{cases*}
    2t+1&if \(0\leq t\leq2\),\\
    \blank[$2t+1$]&if \(\blank <t<\blank\),
    \end{cases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

The output is similar to before. except that the default length of `\blank` is now the length of `\_`, which is slightly shorter.

Comment: Glad to know about `cases*`!

Comment: If you're using the computer modern fonts, you can take advantage of the fact that the digits have a width of .5em; that's more precise than 2mm.

Comment: @barbarabeeton 
This is something that I should know but didn't. Thank you!